# Magento 2 Rename Table metadata lock

Tags: mysql, magento, query-optimization, metadata, magento2

Magento 2 (possibly from cron or scheduled backup) seems to lockup daily and not allow admin users to login on the admin panel. The cause of this issue is a MySQL metadata lock. MySQL is running this query.

```
RENAME TABLE catalog_product_flat_1 TO catalog_product_flat_1_drop_indexer,
             catalog_product_flat_1_tmp_indexer TO catalog_product_flat_1
```

So far it has taken 23407 seconds (6.5 hours) and counting to complete the query. And so far everyday only if the task is killed, admin is allowed to login. There are 16198 records in the table and it seems to be 43 MB in data. How can I resolve this without having the query having to be killed every time it runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely cause is some *other* connection deliberately or accidentally doing *anything* with *either* of those tables.

Look for transactions that are not yet committed.  Look for `ALTERs`.  Etc.

Another thing to check is `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';`  Look for any values that are bigger than 23407.  On my server, I see

```
| interactive_timeout         | 28800    |
| wait_timeout                | 28800    |
```

I addressed these two above.  You could lower them to see if it helps the `RENAME` *next time*.  (Changing these settings won't take effect until a new login.)

```
| lock_wait_timeout           | 31536000 |
```

(as distinct from `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`); don't know about it, but it is suspicious.

```
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout      | 31536000 |
```

That is used with replication.